# Beamer: Removing headline and its space on a single frame (for plan), but keeping the footline

Tags: beamer, spacing, table-of-contents, header-footer

There is now 4 hours that I'm Googling to found a solution to my problem but it's still impossible!

Here is the situation: I have some frames in a presentation using the `Warsaw` theme, on the first one I wanted to remove both headline and footline so I use the `\begin{frame}[plain]`, but I want to, for the next frame, keep the footline but only hide the headline.

I tried the following:

```
{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} %or \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\begin{frame}{Sommaire}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
}
```

But, although the content of the headline is removed, it keeps the space blank (as it is used, but not available for my content). So, there is a white space below my frame title... (Table of Contents).

I don't want to have the plan of my presentation in the header here as it is a frame showing the plan ...

Is there anyone here who could help me?

Comment: Just to add element to my question (and current research...), when I use the `\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]` before the `\begin{document}`, the "white space" is not here on all the frames. But none of the frames have the headline. And here, I want to keep the headline on all the frames except the ones I choose (table of contents here, as the title page is on plain format).

Thanks

Comment: The reason why using `\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]` *before* `\begin{document}` works is that the relevant lengths like `\headheight`, `\textheight`, ... are calculated once (with `\beamer@calculateheadfoot`) at the beginning of the document. Anyway, that's a nice solution you found! `:-)`

Comment: This post is rather old, but in case someone else is facing this problem using beamer. You can use \vskip-20ex to remove spaces just after frame starts as suggested here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56946/beamer-how-to-customise-the-header-of-a-frankfurt-slide

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ok, after more investigation (in the beamer sources :)), I have found the solution.
For those who will search like me in the future, here it is in a simple small example :

```
{ % to delimit a block (we only want to remove the header for this frame)
\makeatletter % to change template
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default] % not mandatory, but I though it was better to set it blank
    \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}} % here is the part we are interested in :)
\makeatother
\begin{frame}{Table of contents} % and our simple frame
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
}
```

It is also possible to define an environment to be able to use it more easily. To do so, use this part of code before the `\begin{document}` :

```
\makeatletter
    \newenvironment{withoutheadline}{
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
        \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
    }{}
\makeatother
```

And for your frame :

```
\begin{withoutheadline}
    \begin{frame}{Table of contents} % and our simple frame
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
\end{withoutheadline}
```

Hope this will help :)

Enjoy!

Comment: How can this be changed, so that _only the text_ (section information) is removed, i.e. the colored bar remains but no information is presented in it?

Comment: If you want to remove the heading in several consecutive frames, or in the entire document, see the answer by den2042.

Comment: Thanks! And to make it a template: `\defbeamertemplate{headline}{noheadline}{}[action]{\def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}}`. To be used as: `\setbeamertemplate{headline}[noheadline]`.

Comment: In my case `\headheight` doesn't remove headline height exactly, it removes a little bit more.

Answer (score 5):

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{noheadline}{
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.9\baselineskip}}{}
}{}
\makeatother
```

With this little modification you can use noheadline environment for several slides together.

```
\begin{noheadline}
\begin{frame}{Table of contents} % and our simple frame
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Table of contents 2} % and our simple frame
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{noheadline}
```