# Beamer - How to customise the header of a frankfurt slide?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I use the following options:

```
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}
```

and this yields a slide which looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible

- to bring 'Section 1' and 'Section 2' closer together?
- to draw a separation line before the frame title ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure. You can redefine the `headline` template; I produced the separation line by using a `beamercolorbox` of `.75ex` height and using the `upper separation line head` color previously set.

Instead of using `\insertnavigation`, I used `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal` which allows for more control. I used the `red` color, since you didn't provide complete information on the color schema used in your code snippet.Feel free to change the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{bg=red}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hfill\hfill}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,ht=.75ex]{upper separation line head}
 \end{beamercolorbox}
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Section Two}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

As **Claudio Fiandrino** mentions in his comment, using

```
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}
```

instead of

```
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hfill\hfill}
```

will produce centered sections in the navigation bar.

The previous approach has a disadvantage: the indicators for subsections are no longer included. To recover the indicators and to get the section titles closer, a redefinition of `\insertnavigation` will be needed:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red!70!black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{bg=red!70!black}

\makeatletter
\def\insertnavigation#1{%
  \vbox{{%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
    \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
    \hbox to #1{\hskip.3cm\setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{\kern1sp}%
      \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
      \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
        \hskip.3cm%
        \global\beamer@section@min@dim\z@
        \dohead%
        \beamer@section@set@min@width
      \box\beamer@sectionbox\hfill\hskip.3cm}%
  }}}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,ht=.75ex]{upper separation line head}
 \end{beamercolorbox}
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Section Three}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three One}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three Two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were faster than me in answering. :) Why not using `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}` to make the sections centered in the navigation bar?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I initially thought so, but I am not sure about the OP's intent; I'll add your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Great! Is it normal that the navigation circles have disappeared?

Comment: @Marco: yes, it's normal! This is the only drawback of this method. Do you want them anyway?

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino: I would have liked them... is it difficult to make them reappeared?

Comment: @Marco: Hmmm... let me think about bringing back the \subsectionhead indicators.

Comment: @Marco: I've updated my answer with a solution showing the the \subsectionhead indicators.

Answer (score 2):

Also a little hackish (or pragmatic if you allow me to sell it :P) version is to reduce the length of the beamercolorbox that holds the navigational items. I actually copy pasted the headline definition from the `smoothbars` theme and added a 0.5 factor. You can adjust how much they should spread out depending on the size/number of sections. I just copied the line solution from Gonzalo's answer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red, bg=white}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{0.5\paperwidth} % <======= Added 0.5 here
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
     \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,ht=.75ex]{upper separation line head}
 \end{beamercolorbox}

}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subintro1}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Important Intro
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subintro2}
\begin{frame}{Dummy frame 1}{Subtitle} \end{frame}
\section{Main Course}
\subsection{Main}
\begin{frame}{Dummy frame 2} \end{frame}
\subsection{Course}
\begin{frame}{Dummy frame 3} \end{frame}
\section{Dessert}
\subsection{Wine}
\begin{frame}{Dummy frame 2} \end{frame}
\subsection{Coffee}
\begin{frame}{Dummy frame 3} \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking at the section titles, it should be a "Yummy frame" ;-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Argh, how did I miss that window of opportunity? :-)