# Beamer: how to change the mini frames from circles to rectangles

Tags: beamer, color, navigation, mini-frames

I would like to change the mini frames from circles to rectangles and also make the already viewed symbols the same color as the background and future symbols the color of foreground.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}
        \subsection{Introduction}   
            \begin{frame}{Frame}        
            \end{frame}

        \subsection{Introduction}   
            \begin{frame}{Frame}
            \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe this could help http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56946/14757

Comment: I had studied that question before posting mine, but didn't understand how the symbols could be changed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `mini frame` and `mini frame in current subsection` templates have a `box` option that will give you squares instead of circles (there's also a `tick` option producing ticks):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[box]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[box]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Test Subsection One}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Two}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Three}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Four}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Five}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the question asked for rectangles, not necessarily squares, the templates (as defined in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`) can be redefined; these templates use `\pgfpathrectangle` to build a rectangle with equal height and width:

```
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@boxsize}{\the\beamer@boxsize}}
```

In the code below I changed it to

```
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\the\dimexpr0.5\beamer@boxsize\relax}{\the\beamer@boxsize}}
```

to have the width be equal to half the height.

To implement the change in the coloring schema, a redefinition of `\slideentry` (original definition in `beamerbasenavigation.sty`) was also necessary. I intentionally left the already visited subsections drawn and not completely blacked out, since one might need to return to a previous slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{.1cm}{.1cm}
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\the\dimexpr0.5\beamer@boxsize\relax}{\the\beamer@boxsize}}
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{.1cm}{.1cm}
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\the\dimexpr0.5\beamer@boxsize\relax}{\the\beamer@boxsize}}
    \pgfsetfillcolor{section in head/foot.bg}
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
  \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#2>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \else%
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
    \fi%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
    \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
          \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
          \ifnum\c@section=#1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection<#2%
              \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
              \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%\beamer@minislidehilight%
              \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%\beamer@minisliderowhilight%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
              \color{fg!50!bg}%
              \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
            \fi%
          \else%
            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            \color{fg!50!bg}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
          \fi%
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
  }\fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi\ignorespaces
  }


\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Test Subsection One}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Two}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Three}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Four}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Five}   
\begin{frame}{Frame}        
test \thepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I posed an updated question about the coloring of the squares here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112220/beamer-how-to-change-the-navigation-symbol-coloring

Comment: Can this be adjusted to achieve the following two goals? 1) Instead of having rectangles, can it become a very thin line (almost like a partial underline under the section title)? And 2) can that indication be “flattened”, so that there is a single partial underline for each subsection (and NOT for each frame)?