# How to keep highlighted the mini frames of already discussed slides?

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I would like for the dots in the mini frame of my beamer presentation to be full circles and remain highlighted once I already discussed the corresponding slide. Let me make this clearer: when you are showing a slide of your presentation, the corresponding dot in the mini frame on top highlights in order to make the audience follow you up. I would like, once I change slide, for the already coloured dots to remain coloured in black. Like in a loading bar. Is that possible to achieve in a simple way? I have, unfortunatly, no time to create my own theme :) 
Thanks a lot in advance to anyone who will have the time and patient to answer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Stile for Beamer
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\useoutertheme[]{miniframes} 

\begin{document}

\section{hello}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Like the coloring schema I suggested in my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111473/3954?

Comment: I have added as requested a sample of my code.

Comment: Yes like you did in [tex.stackexchange.com/a/111473/3954] but the other way around. You made it disappear, I want them to appear. Thank you @GonzaloMedina

Comment: @yrret Is the coloring schem of my answer below what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think so but I am not really able to compile it, as it gives back errors like: undefined control sequence.\slideentry

Comment: @yrret Are you using an updated version of `beamer`? My system uses `beamer.cls    2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revi
sion 332bfd3ce558)`.

Comment: I can not find the version of beamer installed on my mac. I am using texmaker as compiler. How can I find the version I am using?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The animation you show below is exaxctly what I would like to achieve. But it doesn't compile at all your same script using my compiler. I don't know what beamer version I am using, I am sorry but I am not that much of an expert.

Comment: @yrret Let's try to figure out where the problem might be. Please create a fresh new document, and copy-paste the *exact* same code of my answer and nothing else; do you still get errors? (Make sure you use a fresh new document and only the complete and excat code in my answer).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, unfortunatly I already tried that and that's where the problem came out.

Comment: @yrret That's strange. Can you update your LaTeX system to see if the problem was outdated packages?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you so much! I updated my LaTeX system version and it worked! Thank you very much. This was very helpful and I really appreciated your help.

Comment: @yrret You're welcome. Glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a variation of part of the code I provided in [`this answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111473/3954) to [Beamer: how to change the mini frames from circles to rectangles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111438/3954). Here's is the required code (change the color specifications according to the color schema of your theme, if required):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.10} %color for the navigation squares

\makeatletter

\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
  \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#2>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \else%
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
    \fi%
  \hbox to 2pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
    \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
          \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
          \ifnum\c@section>#1%
            \color{dark-gray}%
          \else%
            \ifnum\c@section=#1%
              \ifnum\c@subsection>#2%
                \color{dark-gray}%
              \else%
                \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
                  \ifnum\c@subsectionslide>#3%
                    \color{dark-gray}%
                  \else%
                    \color{dark-gray}%
                  \fi%
                \else%
                  \color{white}%
                \fi%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \color{white}%
            \fi%
          \fi%
          \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
  }\fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi\ignorespaces
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

        \section{Introduction}
            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    1
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    2
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    3
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    4
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    5
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    6
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    7
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    8
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    9
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    10
                \end{frame}                 

        \section{Introduction}
            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    11
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    12
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    13
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    14
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    15
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    16
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    17
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    18
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    19
                \end{frame}

            \subsection{Introduction}   
                \begin{frame}{Frame}
                    20
                \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation showing the result with the desired scheme for the mini frames:

[image]