# Changing Symbol in Frankfurt Headline

Tags: beamer, headline

I would like to change the symbols indicating subsections in the Frankfurt headline to a different symbol, i.e., keep the headline but use ⬥ to indicate a subsection instead of •. Is there a way to change the • to an arbitrary symbol without changing anything else about the theme?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111438/134144

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beamer` offers three different symbols. They can be selected using the appropriate options for

```
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[<option>]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[<option>]
```

and result in the following output:

| `default` | `box` | `tick` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

---

Apart from these predefined symbols, you can of course define your own templates adjusting the original ones you can find in the file `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`.

With the help of symbols from the `unicode-math` package you can for example define your own `diamond` template as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{mini frame}{diamond}
{$\vardiamondsuit$}                                              % symbol for current frame
[action]
{\setbeamersize{mini frame size=.2cm,mini frame offset=0cm}}
\defbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{diamond}
{$\diamondsuit$}                                                 % symbol for other frames
\makeatother
```

and use it with

```
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[diamond]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[diamond]
```

The symbols are responsive to the color theme you select. Here are some examples with diffeent color themes:

| `default` | `beaver` | `wolverine` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

---

You can of course use the same approach for other symbols, for example ones from the `fontawesome5` package:

|  | example 1 | example 2 | example 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| current slide symbol | `\faBookmark` | `\faCheckCircle` | `\faHourglass` |
| other slide's symbol | `\faBookmark[regular]` | `\faCheckCircle[regular]` | `\faHourglass[regular]` |
| output | [image] | [image] | [image] |

---

Compilable MWE for one of these examples:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}


\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{mini frame}{bookmark}
{\faBookmark}
[action]
{\setbeamersize{mini frame size=.2cm,mini frame offset=0cm}}
\defbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{bookmark}
{\faBookmark[regular]}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[bookmark]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[bookmark]

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\begin{frame}
contents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
contents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
contents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```