# I want to change the headline of Warsaw Theme like the following picture?

Tags: headline

My warsaw-theme code is in this overleaf web-address:
[enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/vqmmrjfgjzpk)

In this codes, the headline is as shown as follows:
[image]

But I want the headline to be the following format, that is, replace the 'circle' by '|':
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beamer: how to change the mini frames from circles to rectangles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111438/beamer-how-to-change-the-mini-frames-from-circles-to-rectangles)

Comment: Thanks,  a very useful solution~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```tex
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[tick]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[tick]
```

in your preamble.

Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111473/133968

Comment: Thanks very much~