# Beamer Frankfurt - Spacing in Navigation Bar

Tags: beamer

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=gray!90,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}

\begin{document}

\section[Section 1]{}

\begin{frame}{A concept}


\end{frame}


%newFrame


\section[Section 2]{}


\begin{frame}{A concept}

\end{frame}





\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

As you can see, the labels for Section 1 and 2 are pretty far apart. I'd like to have them next to each other (with some space, maybe 3ex?), or centered.

I tried using the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56946/beamer-how-to-customise-the-header-of-a-frankfurt-slide), but only succeeded in removing the navigation bar altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By redefining a few macros, you can replace the space between the sections with a fixed width. The place is marked with `% <- Adjust here the desired space` in the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=gray!90,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}

\makeatletter
\def\insertnavigation#1{%
  \vbox{{%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
    \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
    \beamer@ypos@offset=0\relax%
    \hbox to #1{\hskip.3cm\setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{\kern1sp}%
      \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
      \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
%        \hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill%
        \global\beamer@section@min@dim\z@
        \dohead%
        \beamer@section@set@min@width
      \box\beamer@sectionbox\hfil\hskip.3cm}%
  }}}

\def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{% section number, section title, page
  \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
  \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
  \beamer@ypos@offset=0\relax%
  \ifnum#5=\c@part%
  \beamer@section@set@min@width%
  \box\beamer@sectionbox%
%  \hskip1.875ex plus 1fill%
    \quad% <- Adjust here the desired space
  \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=
  \hbox{\def\insertsectionhead{#2}%
    \def\insertsectionheadnumber{#1}%
    \def\insertpartheadnumber{#5}%
    {%
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
      \ifnum\c@section=#1%
        \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}}%
      \else%
        \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}%
      \fi}%
  }%
  \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
  \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
  \fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section[Section 1]{}

\begin{frame}{A concept}


\end{frame}


%newFrame


\section[Section 2]{}


\begin{frame}{A concept}

\end{frame}





\end{document}
```

[image]

(please note, you don't need `xcolor` with beamer)