# Background image does not cover the entire page

Tags: beamer, graphics, backgrounds

My title page has a background image. However, when the presentation has sections (that create a navigation bar), there is a white box on top of the image. How can I get rid of it?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}   % 
\graphicspath{ {./graphics/} }
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{square-land-background.jpg}}%

\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
}


\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{a}
\end{frame}


\section{first part}
\begin{frame}{b}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I tried both solutions to this question: [Beamer: Removing headline and its space on a single frame (for plan), but keeping the footline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44983/20929) but they did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A native beamer solution without additional packages:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vskip\headheight}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}%
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
}


\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{a}
\end{frame}


\section{first part}
\begin{frame}{b}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the main change is "\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vskip\headheight}", right? This works excellent. Thanks!

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Yes, that's the relevant change. This just removes the space reserved for the headline.

Comment: @samcarter Could you help me understand why adding a positive value skip `\vskip\headheight` to `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` removes the headline space?

Comment: @JonathanKomar That is either deep beamer voodoo or very dirty hack (up to you which term you want to use) :) The trick is to make the headline heigher than the space reserved for it (anything larger than `\vskip\headheight`) will do. Because beamer only calculates the headheight at the start of the document, this will shift the main content of the frame relative to the headline, but the headline will nevertheless only start at the top of the page -> voila the image is shifted upwards.

Answer (score 5):

Set the image at page shipout as an overlay (using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % remove navigation symbols

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title page}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}%
  }
}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{a}
\end{frame}

\section{first part}
\begin{frame}{b}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\usebackgroundtemplate` places the background image below the header. When you use `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`, you are only clearing the header contents, not deleting it, so what remains is the white background canvas.

One option is to define the background as an explicitly positioned `tikzpicture`. This will initially require two builds in order to place the image correctly, and the image will appear as the background for all frames. The following code shows the difference.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}%

\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{a}
\end{frame}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\section{first part}
\begin{frame}{b}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]