# Suppress section counter in appendix slides

Tags: beamer

I would like to have a references slide at the end of my presentation where the slide is neither counted in the slide count nor counted as part of a section (which puts a circle in the header of the slide).

Not counting the reference slide in the slide count is taken care of using `\appendix` as in [Don't count backup slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70448/dont-count-backup-slides).

However, there is still a filled in circle in the header and it looks bad. How can I remove the circle? The solution in [Beamer: Removing headline and its space on a single frame (for plan), but keeping the footline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44983/beamer-removing-headline-and-its-space-on-a-single-frame-for-plan-but-keepin) is too strong since it also removes the basic styling of the header and I want to only remove the section circle.

I would even be happy if the original headline with the list of sections persisted onto the appendix slide; I just think the one random circle in an otherwise blank headline looks awful.

Here is my code. It is probably helpful to note that I'm using a custom footline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

%custom footline: adds author name in left, title in middle, pagecount in right
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, left]{title in head/foot}%
     \hspace{1em} \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor%~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, right]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1em}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
Some content
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}{References}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did Jojo's answer help solve your question ?

Comment: @BambOo It didn't answer my question (see my comments on Jojo's answer), which is why I've left the answer unaccepted. It did help in that it pointed out what code to play with, so maybe an upvote is deserved.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to get rid of the circle, the quick and dirty way is to uncomment the part where it is inserted.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\plainheadline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    %\vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

%custom footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline} % For custom footer. Adds author name in left, title in middle, pagecount in right
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, left]{title in head/foot}%
     \hspace{1em} \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor%~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, right]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1em}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
Some content
\end{frame}

\appendix
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\plainheadline}
\begin{frame}{References}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This method gets rid of the circle, but affects the stylization of the header (it moves one of the horizontal lines that the theme puts in for style).

Comment: Replacing the commented out line with \vskip17.5pt got the spacing just right.